# Google Map does not display in Android -not display map except boxes and zooming button

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed an android app using google maps api. I created and used an api key, even but the map is not shown/visible as expected. Grey color title & zoom button are show/visible.

I followed this [Link](http://ramsandroid4all.blogspot.com/2013/03/google-maps-android-api-v2.html)

My application is unsigned application.

This map file location(package) available in com.xont.hema6.controller.sale but main package is com.xont.hema6.controller . which one needs to be specified for key?

My code is :

```
   public class RetailerMapActivity extends FragmentActivity{
GoogleMap map;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = fm.getMap();

}
```

This is my xml

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".sale.RetailerMapActivity" >   

<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"        
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

AndroidMainfest file permission

```
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
<permission  android:name="com.xont.hema6.controller.sale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.xont.hema6.controller.sale.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS"></uses-permission>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

inside application

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"    android:value="AIza**CD3c**JoP27sH_EsGTR7ul***w_G3pS7o"/>
```

http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/

Please anyone suggest that what is wrong in my code.

Comment: you used signed or unsigned apk to test in real device?

Comment: Google map v2 will not display in emulator, try with physical device...

Comment: I tried in Galaxy tab 2 7.0 device. Not show the map. Title & zoom button are avaaibale

Comment: unsigned  application.

Comment: Is the package of your app in google console the correct one?

Comment: This map file available in `com.xont.hema6.controller.sale` but main package is `com.xont.hema6.controller` . which on need to specify for key?

Comment: As per to original [Google Maps V2 API documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specifying_permissions), you're currently missing a permission in your manifest file - `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. According to doc, this permission `Allows the API to cache map tile data in the device's external storage area.`. Add it and see if it works for you.

Comment: I added `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` this permission also. Still It show grey color tiles boxes & zoom icon only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your manifest file see your package name by use this package name you must create Google Maps API V2 key and use

Ex:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.venky.loadgooglemapsdemo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

My package name is "com.venky.loadgooglemapsdemo"

If you want Tutorial and Demo please see this [link](http://venkoolit.blogspot.in/2013/05/tutorial-for-develop-google-maps-in-api.html)

Comment: I  did according to your link.  Still It show grey color tiles boxes & zoom icon only .Pls any suggestion

Comment: Import my demo project and use "com.venky.maps" this package name you create Google Maps API V2 key and copy paste into manifest.xml file and run. It success. You hava an idea.

Comment: Thaks It working . Uninstall my app & installed it again , now is ok.

Answer (score 2):

May be your Problem is You are using

```
1)Wrong Package name
or
2)Wrong SHA1
or
3)Wrong API V2 key
```

Go to your manifest file see your package name thats your package name.

```
1) Goto command prompt and type this command

    keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Documents and
    Settings\<your_user_name>\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -
    storepass android -keypass android

Get your SHA1 key

2) Goto Google API console switch on Google Maps API V2 and create new Android key.

Give your_SHA1key;your_packagename

3)Take API V2 key paste into your manifest file and run
```

[image]